# How to maintain jmeter scripts in an agile environment

Tags: jmeter, agile

We are following agile for our s/w development & we get a new build every 2 days. So how should i maintain my jmeter scripts. Which tool will help me in maintaining the scripts so that i can see the gradual improvement or degradation of our product

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you're looking for a [continuous integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) tool, if you have a build server which compiles your product, runs unit tests, packages it, etc. you can add your JMeter tests as an extra step to act as [regression test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_testing)

If you don't have specific continuous integration solution in mind I'd recommend going for [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/), it's free, open source and Java-based so you won't require to setup an "alien" runtime.

With regards to JMeter and Jenkins integration there is [Performance Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-jenkins-performance-plugin) which is capable of displaying performance trends you're looking for across builds and also can mark builds as unstable or failed depending on metrics thresholds.

[image: JMeter Jenkins Performance Plugin Report]

Comment: Thank u Dmitri..I will surely try Jenkins

Comment: Hi Dmitri now i am facing an issue with the Performance Plug-in configuration i suppose. I am running Jenkins as a .war file & have copied the plugin to the .jenkins/plugins path under "C:\Users\Swarup.user-PC\.jenkins\plugins" folder. But under Jenkins -> Your Project -> Configure -> Add post-build i don't see Publish Performance Test Result Report option. So do i need to copy the full folder named "performance-plugin-master" or the contents inside it to the Jenkins plugins folder. Also is it mandatory to install taurus for this feature to work??

Comment: Go to `Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugins -> Available` and search for Performance Plugin

Comment: There are no plugins under the Available tab. Do i need to move the Jenkins folder under Tomcat folder to get the available plugins. Also i don't see any .hpi file under the performance plugin that i downloaded. Can you please tell me why so..Also is it mandatory to install taurus for this feature to work??